# A criterion for finite abelian group to embed into a symmetric group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Write $G\approx \mathbb{Z}/p_1^{i_1}\mathbb{Z}\times\dots \mathbb{Z}/p_m^{i_m}\mathbb{Z}$, with $m\ge 0$, $p_1,\dots,p_m$ primes (not necessarily distinct) and $i_k\ge 1$ for all $k$.

For $n\ge 0$, is it true that there is an injective homomorphism $G\rightarrow S_n$ if and only if $p_1^{i_1}+\dots+p_m^{i_m}\leq n$?

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users

Comment: If you intend the primes $p_{i}$ to be distinct, then the group you describe is cyclic. If you allow repetition of primes, then you will pick up all finite Abelian groups.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is true (provided we add the hypothesis $i_1, \ldots, i_n \ge 1$), and not hard to prove by considering centralizers of products of cycles in symmetric groups.

According to http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Povzner.html, the minimum degree of a permutation representation of an arbitrary abelian group was found in A. Ya. Povzner, *Finding groups of permutations of least degree which are isomorphic to a
given Abelian group*, Kharkov Mat. Obshch., **14** (1937) 151–158. (I have not been able to obtain this paper to check.)

Theorem 4.1 in Kay Jin Lim, *Specht modules with abelian vertices*, 
J. Algebraic Combin. **35** (2012) 157–171 states your conjectured result in the special case when all the primes are the same with a reference to Povzner's paper.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Your notation $n$ is used for two different meanings, so let me denote by $m$ the number of summands. A homomorphism $G\to S_n$ correspond to an action of $G$ on a set with $n$ elements, which can be split into orbits $A_1,...,A_\ell$. Each orbit can can be provided with a structure of a group with a surjective homomophism $G\to A_i$. Then, the condition is precisely that the induced map $G\to \oplus_i A_i$ is injective. Note the total number of cyclic summands in the right hand side is at least $n$. If $A_i$ is not cyclic, using $ab\ge a+b$ for $a,b>1$, we see that it only decreases the sum of sizes if we split $A_i$ into two parts corresponding to a decomposition $A_i = B\oplus C$. So we may assume that all the $A_i$-s are cyclic of order a prime power. By comparing each primary component at a time, we may assume that all the $p_i$-s are a single prime $p$. The result now follows from the following standard lemma

Lemma: Let $\phi: \oplus_i \mathbb{Z}/p^{a_i} \to \oplus_j \mathbb{Z}/p^{b_j}$ be injective, with $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge ...\ge a_k$ and $b_1 \ge ...\ge b_\ell$. Then $a_i \le b_i$.

edit: As mensioned correctly by @Richard Lyons, the proof I gave for it was totally incorrect so I deleted it. Here's an hopefully less wrong proof, im really sorry for that.

Let $A\subseteq B$ be abelian finite $p$-groups. Write $B=\mathbb{Z}/p^k \oplus B'$ for $B'$ of exponent smaller than or equal $k$. Let $B\to \mathbb{Z}/p^k$ be the projection. If the composition 
$A\to B\to \mathbb{Z}/p^k$ is not surjective, then $A$ is contained in $p\mathbb{Z}/p^k \oplus B$ and we can proceed by induction onthe total number of elements of $B$. Otherwise $A$ contains an element of the form $(1,b)$ for $b\in B'$. Since the exponent of $B'$ is no more than $k$, there is a map $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\to B'$ mapping $1$ to $b$, and so by applying the automorphism $(x,c)\mapsto (x,c-xb)$ we may assume that $(1,0)$ is in $A$. It follows then that $A=\mathbb{Z}/p^k \oplus A\cap B'$ and we proceed by induction on the number of summands.

Comment: the point about notation is a good one, thanks.

Comment: @RichardLyons thank you very much! I hope the new version is correct, but after such a silly mistake Im not sure anymore what is right and what is wrong :-)